Kamal + Grover::JavaScript::TimeoutError
I'm using Kamal to deploy a Sinatra web app and within that I'm using Grover to process pdfs. The problem I've got is that when I to https://myserver.com/pdf3 I get the following error;
Grover::JavaScript::TimeoutError at /pdf3
Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

Here is my routes,
get "/up" do 
  "UP"
end

get '/pdf2' do          # Works
  grover = Grover.new("https://www.google.com")
  content_type 'application/pdf'
  attachment 'output.pdf'
  grover.to_pdf
end

get '/pdf3' do          # Timeout error
  grover = Grover.new("https://myserver.com/up")
  content_type 'application/pdf'
  attachment 'output.pdf'
  grover.to_pdf
end

If I call http://myserver.com/pdf2 then grover works and puts the google website into a PDF and sends it to my browser. I want to be able to call itself but it seems to hang the process and all other processes whilst it's timing out.
I'm also using a nginx proxy with the following setup;
server {
    server_name myserver.com;
    limit_rate 50k;
    access_log off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}

My Dockerfile
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1

# Make sure RUBY_VERSION matches the Ruby version in .ruby-version and Gemfile
ARG RUBY_VERSION=2.7.8
FROM ruby:$RUBY_VERSION-slim as base

# Rails app lives here
WORKDIR /sinatra

RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y build-essential ruby-dev libmagick++-dev curl \
    ssh software-properties-common npm  

RUN npm install npm@latest -g && \
    npm install n -g && \
    n latest

RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

COPY . /sinatra
RUN bundle install
RUN npm install

ENV GROVER_NO_SANDBOX="true"
ENV DISABLE_JEMALLOC="true"
# ENV RACK_ENV="production"

EXPOSE 4567

CMD ["bundle", "exec", "rackup", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "4567"]

My deploy.yml
# Name of your application. Used to uniquely configure containers.
service: myserver

# Share the users directory for SSH key use
volumes:
  - "/home/map7:/home/map7"
    
# Name of the container image.
image: map7/myserver

# Deploy to these servers.
servers:
  - 11.111.111.111

# Credentials for your image host.
registry:
  # Specify the registry server, if you're not using Docker Hub
  # server: registry.digitalocean.com / ghcr.io / ...
  username: myuser

  # Always use an access token rather than real password when possible.
  password:
    - KAMAL_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

# Inject ENV variables into containers (secrets come from .env).
# Remember to run `kamal env push` after making changes!
env:
  secret:
    - REPORTS_USER
    - REPORTS_PASS

# Configure builder setup.
builder:
  multiarch: false

# Configure custom arguments for Traefik. Be sure to reboot traefik when you modify it.
traefik:
  host_port: "127.0.0.1:8081"
  options:
    cpus: 2    


# Configure a custom healthcheck (default is /up on port 3000)
healthcheck:
  path: /healthz
  port: 4567

It's like there is only one process going at a time and with the route /pdf3 I'm calling the same server nested within. How do I fix this problem?

I managed to fix this by swapping from the default 'thin' server to using 'puma' instead.

Add puma GEM

Dockerfile: Change over to puma
CMD ["bundle", "exec", "puma", "-b", "tcp://0.0.0.0", "-p", "4567"]

Commit

Deploy
kamal deploy


Thin is only accepting one connection at a time, whilst puma by default allows multiple connections.
